# Please Correct my code. Please tell me, what is happening here with this code

Tags: c#

The problem, i am facing in this code is that first iteration of loop is good but in second iteration when i press y program gives error.
Error = Input string was not in a correct format.

Line of Error = my = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a, my;
    char again = 'y';
    while ((again == 'y' || again=='Y'))
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the value for your number = ");
        my = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Random b = new Random();
        a = b.Next(1, 6);
        if (a == my)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("you Lost");
            Console.WriteLine("My no is {0}.", a);
        }
        Console.Write("Again? Then press 'y' or 'Y' = ");
        again = (char)Console.Read();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: And that error would be? Press the [copy exception details to clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Didyouknowyoucancopytheexceptiondetailsw_F67C/image_2.png) button and then paste the text here [as a edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482162/correction-in-my-code-please-tell-me-what-is-happening-here-in-this-code) be sure to highlight the text and press the button that looks like `{ }` to make it display correctly on the site.

Comment: The title of this question is so vague as to be useless. It could apply to pretty much any question on the site. Please revise so it will contribute to the usefulness of the site to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
again = (char)Console.Read();
```

to

```
again = (char)Console.ReadLine().First();
```

`Console.Read` Reads the next character from the standard input stream. To continue you press a key ('y' in this case) and press 'enter'. Which means you input 2 characters and read 1. Which one is read by next `Console.Readline`. So, you never get the actual string in this line

```
my = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Rather you get the character you did not read previously. And this one can not be parsed to integer.

Comment: So nice.......... But please explain it .. .

Comment: Just edited the post to add some explanation.

Comment: ok very good i got it. So Nice

Answer (score 0):

If you got `Input string was not in a correct format` in a `Int32.Parse`, try replace it for a `Int32.TryParse`

```
Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out my);
```